# How to Break Up Large tcpdump Files

Tags: tcpdump

Is there something that can break up tcpdump file *after* the captuure and make sure the breaks are on the border of packet data?

Like `-C` but after the fact.

Comment: is it because the files are too big or that you want them easier to read?

Comment: djangofan: To big, When I load them into wireshark it faults because it can't allocate the memory.  Only grabbing the default 96 snap, but they are for whole days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've used `editcap` in the past, with great success.

```
editcap -c 1000 large-in.pcap smaller-out
```

That command should generate one or more files named `smaller-out-00000`, `smaller-out-00001` and so on, containing the firs, second, etc thousand packets from the input file.

Answer (score 4):

[TCPSplit](http://www.icir.org/mallman/software/tcpsplit/) will do this.  It even makes sure that you don't lose TCP sessions in the break.

Comment: I've used tcpsplit for files up to 40GB, and it worked great.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `editcap` to do split based on number of packets (or time range), or if you really need to split based on size, try [this](http://www.badpenguin.co.uk/files/pcap-util) script.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `csplit`?

Comment: csplit isn't very useful on binary files...

Answer (score 1):

To simply split to a manageable size, you should be able to do it with tcpdump itself, using -C, -w and -r options. but I have not tried it.